# Child route redirect not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to set up the default child route for an angular component but I can't seem to get it working with either of the methods below. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'signin', component: SignInComponent, canActivate: [UnauthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
]);

RouterModule.forChild([{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    // { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  ]
}]);
```

Comment: Is it getting properly exported/import into the parent routing module? Do you have the correct order in your app module?

Comment: @Z.Bagley All routes are working except for the empty one so I think so

Comment: You're not loading the children in your .forRoot. Your `path: ''` should loadChildren in some fashion, and shouldn't load a component.

Comment: I can provide an answer with examples if needed.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Awesome, moving the main component routes to the main route file did the trick. How would I go about moving the main component routes to a separate file though? Can you also post an answer so I can flag the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your base href route doesn't load the forChild route anywhere. There are several different methods for loading children into routes, but here's my standard:

In your base app **routing.module.ts**, import the sub-module that is holding your child routes.

```
import { ChildModule } from './child/child.module';
```

For production builds I add a simple export function for AOT compiling:

```
export function loadChildModule() {
  return ChildModule;
}
```

and your `@NgModule` should declare the child routes like:

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: loadChildModoule },
{ path: '', component: MainComponent }
```

Your **child/child.module.ts** will need to import the routes from **child/child-routing.modules.ts**.

child.module will contain:

```
import { ChildRoutingModule } from './child-routing.module';
...
*NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ChildRoutingModule
  ]
...
```

and your child-routing.module:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ChildComponent2 } from './child2/child2.component';
import { ChildComponent3 } from './child3/child3.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'child2', component: ChildComponent2 },
  { path: 'child3', component: ChildComponent3 },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule { }
```

You can add children to the child module as well in the same way you added them to the the main app `RoutingModule`. Also note, that you can use a similar setup as your .forChild routes posted in the question. The only difference is you will have to use at least one named route (for example your main component would have path: 'home' and there should be a redirect to path: '' to redirectTo: 'home' ) in each `.forChild`.

Answer (score 0):

Write: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on father component. 
in this case write on MainComponent.